# How to use value from dictionary returned by QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django

I wrote this query

`p_name = OrderLine.objects.filter(order_id=order).values('product_name')`

and it is returning the following results

`<QuerySet [{'product_name': 'doc 1 (1-1000)'}]>`

I want to use only `doc 1 (1-1000)` as a string. Is there a method for this. I read on some website to use `.values()` but is returning `[{'product_name': 'doc 1 (1-1000)'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `values_list()` + `flat=True` to generate a list instead.

```
>>> p_name = OrderLine.objects.filter(order_id=order).values_list('product_name',flat=True)
>>> print(p_name)
>>> <QuerySet ['doc 1 (1-1000)']>
```

This is meant to generate a list of values from the field passed in `value_list()`. In case you are sure that this will have only one value and it's the one wanted, you may index the item in the list:

```
>>> p_name[0]
>>> 'doc 1 (1-1000)'
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Lemayzeur answer. But you can also use the code as you have it, in two ways:

```
p_name.first() # this will return the dictionary itself
```

Or you can convert the queryset into a list using

```
list(p_name)
```

It's not the recommended way, but it may come handy in other situations.

Cheers!